# document.Write() overwriting all page content

Tags: javascript, html

I understand this question has been asked many times, so tried a few things before considering posting, but still ended up here anyway.
I now understand that document.Write() overwrites page content without being pointed to anything, so I gave it a div to play with.

I have an empty div that looks like this:

```
<div id="audio"></div>
```

And my JS now looks like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    var numberOfSongs = 3 
    var sound = new Array(numberOfSongs+1)
    sound[0]= "key1.mp3"
    sound[1]= "key2.mp3" 
    sound[2]= "key3.mp3"
    function randomNumber(){
    var randomLooper = -1
    while (randomLooper < 0 || randomLooper > numberOfSongs || isNaN(randomLooper)){    randomLooper = parseInt(Math.random()*(numberOfSongs+1))
    }
        return randomLooper
    }
    var randomsub = randomNumber()
    var soundFile = sound[randomsub]
    document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML ('<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true autostart=true loop=true>')
}
```

If it looks a bit messy that's probably because I have just started learning JS, bridging across from C# so it might just be that my syntax is off  bit.

As it was before:

```
document.Write ('<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true autostart=true loop=true>')
```

It did play a sound before wiping the page, now I get nothing at all, no sound and nothing in the HTML shows up, so I am at a complete loss as to what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is a property not a function,

```
document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = 
   '<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true autostart=true loop=true>';
```

In your console, you should see an error like *innerHTML is not a function*.

Comment: Ah, just noticed this; but all the answers I could find online said to use this.

Comment: @K.Briggs Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer. If you feel that it helped you. And this is not a compulsion. :)